# Unique index in mongodb using db.command

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo, unique-index

I am using `mongodb` with `PyMongo` and I would like to separate schema definition from the rest of the application. I have file `user_schema.json`with schema for `user` collection:

```
{
  "collMod": "user",
  "validator": {
    "$jsonSchema": {
      "bsonType": "object",
      "required": ["name"],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "bsonType": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in `db.py`:

```
with open("user_schema.json", "r") as coll:
    data = OrderedDict(json.loads(coll.read())) # Read JSON schema.
    name = data["collMod"] # Get name of collection.
    db.create_collection(name) # Create collection.
    db.command(data) # Add validation to the collection.
```

Is there any way to add unique index to `name` field in `user` collection without changing `db.py` (only by changing `user_schema.json`)? I know I can use this:

```
db.user.create_index("name", unique=True)
```

however, then I have information about the collection in two places. I would like to have all configuration of the collection in the `user_schema.json` file. I need something like that:

```
{
  "collMod": "user",
  "validator": {
    "$jsonSchema": {
       ...
    }
  },
  "index": {
    "name": {
      "unique": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you won't be able to do that without changing db.py.

The contents of user_schema.json is an object that can be passed to `db.command` to run the [collmod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collMod/index.html) command.

In order to create an index, you need to run the [createIndexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createIndexes/#createindexes) command, or one of the helpers that calls this.

It is not possible to complete both of these actions with a single command.

A simple modification would be to store an array of commands to run in user_schema.json, and have db.py iterate the array and run each command.